# stud or haproxy as front facing?

Tags: haproxy

I'm planning to use haproxy to proxy a tls service that IS NOT http at the backend.

Is there any reason why you'd use stud as the front facing app vs haproxy then stud?

i.e.

1) INTERNET -> stud -> haproxy -> tls service

over

2) INTERNET -> haproxy -> stud -> tls service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious reasons for putting stud at the outside are:

- Stud doesn't does not have a native method for SSL session sharing across nodes - whether this is relevant depends on the mystery protocol.
- if you want to distribute the traffic based on content other than the source/dest IP address

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of haproxy added SSL termination capability. But if for any reason you are happier with stud, you should put it in front of haproxy. stud is also able to pass client's IP address to haproxy in case you have any policy that requires end-user IP address. (`--write-proxy` option).